# QR decomposition implementation in maple

Tags: maple

The QR algorithm should converge to the Eigenvalues of the input matrix A, after several iterations, but in my case it doesn't. I want to use the Eigenvalues to find singular values, hence the input. I want to do this, without any built in functions.

```
restart:
with(LinearAlgebra):
B := RandomMatrix(3);
B := BidiagonalForm(B);
A := evalf(Matrix([[Matrix(3),Transpose(B)],[B,Matrix(3)]]));
C := A;
t0 := time():
 for k from 1 to 300 do
  Q, R := QRDecomposition(A);
  A:=R.Q;
 end do:
time() - t0;
Diagonal(A);
sort(%);
abs(Eigenvalues(C));
```

The last line is to check the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is **C**? You ask for the eigenvalues of **C**, but you never set its value in your code.

Comment: C := A; before the for cycle